# ignore Rack::Timeout middle in specific rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-middleware

I have installed rack-timeout gem and created rack_timeout.rb inside the initializers.I have set Rack::Timeout.service_timeout = 1 inside rack_timeout.rb.I want to restrict the rack-timeout to halt the execution if timeout exceeded in controllers other than controllers inside api.Only the api controllers' execution should be stopped.I have created a custom middleware inside lib named my_middleware.rb

```
 class MyMiddleware < Rack::Timeout
  def initialize(app, options = {})
    @app = app
    @exclude = options[:exclude]
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['PATH_INFO'].include? "api"
      super(env)
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

config/development.rb

```
config.middleware.use "MyMiddleware"
```

but its not working.everywhere rack timeout is throwing the exception when timeout happened.

Comment: the best way to do that is to actually create two distinct rails app, although you can share models and many things as custom gems

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question. It's not a very good practice to timeout your requests outside of whenever they are being executed from, but it seems like there is no other ready-to-go solution.

I went ahead and forked `rack_timeout`, and added filtering based on request paths, slightly based on your code.

Basically, it extends `Rack::Timeout` with `Select` class

```
class Select < Timeout
  def call(env)
    if exclude_or_any?(env) #checking for parameters passed on init
      super(env)
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

It is using the original initialize method and accepts 2 additional parameters:

- `exclude: ["paths", "to", "exclude"]` - Do not run timeout for requests coming from paths containing strings provided.
- `only: ["only_timeout_this"]` - Only process requests with from those paths.

I would not recommend using it on a regular basis since it's better to keep your timeouts within whatever processes your requests, but for the sake of development and simplicity, it should be enough.

More information available in the repo:

- [Source](https://github.com/mkrl/rack-timeout)
- [Demo application](https://github.com/mkrl/rack-timeout-test)